# Как отложить выполнение скрипта плагина в Wordpress до появления объекта в поле зрения

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть плагин "Elementor". В нем, в свою очередь, есть опция "Fancy Text", которая позволяет аниммировать текст. Как сделать так, чтобы он начинал аниммировать только когда сам текст появляется в поле зрения?

Answer (score 1):

Откройте у текстового блока/заголовка раздел `Advanced` -> `Motition Effects` и там поставьте галочку S`crolling Effects`, а дальше будет понятно.

Более подробно можно [поглядеть](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyOtp9Wt0gI) в официальном блоге Elementor;